# Tetris GUI by coloring JButtons. Problems with rendering

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, tetris

I am making a Tetris game and for my GUI I chose to color JButtons to use as my tetris board. I set up a grid of JButtons. I plan to loop through the Tetris grid that is returned from

```
newGrid = game.gamePlay(oldGrid);
```

and color each JButton based on the integer in each grid element. The Tetris grid returned is an array of integers, each number representing a color. As of now I have no user interaction, I am just trying to have the basic GUI where the blocks drop straight down.

```
final JPanel card3 = new JPanel();
// Tetris setup
JButton startGame = new JButton("START GAME");
card3.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 2, 2, 2);
card3.add(startGame, gbc2);
gbc.gridy = 1;
startGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    card3.remove(0); //remove start button

    Game game = new Game();
    int[][] oldGrid = null;
    int[][] newGrid = null;
    boolean firstTime = true;

    JButton[][] grid; // tetris grid of buttons
    card3.setLayout(new GridLayout(20, 10));
    grid = new JButton[20][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            grid[i][j] = new JButton();
            card3.add(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }               

    while (true) {
            if (firstTime) {
                newGrid = game.gamePlay(null);
            } else {
                newGrid = game.gamePlay(oldGrid);
            }

            //Coloring Buttons based on grid

            oldGrid = newGrid;
            firstTime = false;
            card3.revalidate();
        }
    }
});
```

And here is the code from the Game class

```
public class Game
{
    static Tetris game;

    public int[][] gamePlay(int[][] grid) {
        if (grid == null) {
            game = new Tetris();
            System.out.println("first time");
        }
        else {
                game.setGrid(grid);
            }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        game.move_Down();
        game.print_Game();

        return game.getGrid();
    }
}
```

The game.print_Game(); prints the grid to the console window so that I can see textually what is going on. But the card3.revalidate(); does not seem to be working because the GUI suspends when the printing begins. If I move the revalidate before the while loop and then comment out the while loop, the GUI outputs:

[image]

which is what I want. But in order to color the buttons a certain color, I need to do the revalidating in the while loop as the grid changes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can I just ask... *why* are you using JButtons?

Comment: Use a javax.swing.Timer instead of the while loop

Comment: I actually decided to use a JTable...I don't know what I was thinking to be honest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. use `GridLayout` (simpler `LayoutManager`) instead of `GridBagLayout`
2. use `Swing Timer` instead of `Runnable#Thread`
3. `while (true) {` is endless loop
4. `Thread.sleep(1000);` can to freeze Swing GUI untill sleep ended, endless loop with `Thread.sleep` can caused unresponsible application
5. can't see there `JButton.setBackground(somecolor)`
6. use KeyBindings (add to the to `JButtons container`) for rotations

Comment: I decided to use a JTable. For some reason because tetris usually has 3D looking blocks I thought using buttons would have the similar effect. I know the infinite loop was in there I just wanted to see if I could get the pieces to drop into place.